# JPA @OneToMany bidirectional with @JoinTable - Not including all columns in insert query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to persist a OneToMany parent child relation with Join table, but in insert sql for join table only one column is considered (out of two).

```
insert into ITEM_BIDS_REL (BID_ID) values (?)
```

It does not include `ITEM_ID` column and due to that getting below error.

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BIDDING_SYSTEM_OWNER"."ITEM_BIDS_REL"."ITEM_ID")

**Two question here:**

1. Why it only includes `BID_ID` column in INSERT query for `ITEM_BIDS_REL` join table.
2. Is the right way to design JOIN TABLE like I have kept `BID_ID` ad PK,FK and `ITEM_ID` as FK.

Use case:
Referring the "Online Action (bidding) System" example from Java Persistence with Hibernate book.
An Item can have many Bids on it.

**ITEM table**

1. ITEM_ID PK
2. NAME
3. INITIAL_AMOUNT

**ITEM_BIDS table**

1. BID_ID PK
2. AMOUNT

**ITEM_BIDS_REL Join Table**

1. BID_ID PK (FK from ITEM_BIDS table)
2. ITEM_ID  NOT NULL (FK from ITEM table)

Entity classes:

**Item Class**

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "ITEM_BIDS_REL",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BID_ID"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Bid> bids;
```

**Bid class**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ITEM_BIDS_REL",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "BID_ID", insertable = false,
                    updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", insertable = false,
                    updatable = false)})
    private Item item;
```

**Persistence logic:**

```
public Item addBid(BidDTO bidDTO) {

    Item item = itemsRepository.findOne(bidDTO.getItemId());

    Bid bid = Bid.builder()
                .item(item)
                .bidAmount(bidDTO.getBidAmount())
                .build();

    if(item.getBids() == null){
        item.setBids(new HashSet<>());
    }
    item.getBids().add(bid);

    bidRepository.save(bid);

    itemsRepository.save(item);

    return item;
}
```

Comment: @Richard Telford, this question couldn't get any attention yet. Did I miss something while putting this question like correct tags or anything w.r.t. the statck overflow process. Actually I have no experience about putting question on stack overflow, this is the first question from my side.